# Serializing html and css, and storing in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, html, serialization

I am in the process of developing an html template generator. I would like to store the templates in a mysql database (or text files if that would be more efficient). I am looking for the best way to serialize the html and css, and then reproduce the original efficiently.

Javascript and php will be used to create/edit/and remove elements from both the browser and the database for later reproduction.

Elements can be added such as div, p, a, etc. and nesting should not be an issue. The main problem I am having is if a div is nested within a div and a paragraph element is nested within the second div at a later time, how would all of this be stored in a database? Elements will be deleted and new elements will be added in random order.

I hope this was somewhat clear. I am not really looking for code, but suggestions on how all of this would work together.  Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Store the entire thing as a blob in a single field in the database. Unless you're doing something quite novel, there's no reason the database layer needs to have an in-depth understanding of DOM structure.

Comment: So when editing the page by adding or deleting an element, the blob would be read, modified, then updated? Would this be more efficient than editing individual text files?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response by the way

Comment: Don't forget the mysql_real_escape_string() before you insert and mysql_strip_slashes() when reading back.

Comment: @Tony way more efficient. That's how pretty much every CMS works (including the one my team owns, which just happens to store about a million of said pages).

Comment: @Rasika always store the original in the DB - scrub reading out, not in.

Comment: @Tony, performance wise I think the text files will be quicker. However, if you are looking at multiple users editing the files, you could use locking and other fancy operations on the DB and hard to do this on text files.

Comment: @Rex M, you need to escape the strings before you put in the DB unless you are sure that no one can use malicious formatting in the input (which will eventually come in the UI).

Comment: @Rasika for I/O in a low-transaction environment, flat files *might* be better. But in a scalable CMS a database is more or less unavoidable.

Comment: @Rasika you are mistaken - you want to scrub the data to remove malicious markup at the *last* point before it reaches the UI.

Comment: Uh oh, conflicting suggestions...maybe ill add more details to the situation. There will be many users, with each user editing their own multiple templates (not a team editing type of thing), and the templates will need to be downloaded at some point. Maybe this will narrow things down a bit

Comment: @Tony I'd suggest waiting until @Rasika actually posts a helpful answer. Databases are built to deal with the issues inherent in your situation - concurrency, transactions, etc. They also build in layers of caching, scalability, portability, and maintainability that you don't easily get with a pile of flat files.

Comment: So you think text files will be better in this situation? As apposed to a hierarchy system database or blobs?

Comment: @Tony no, I would absolutely not use text files in this situation. Blobs in the database are the most common solution to this type of problem.

Comment: Ha okay thank you, that last post threw me off a bit. And scrub data before being stored into the database? Or before pulling it to the UI?

Comment: @Tony I can't find the post at the moment, but even the people that built this site (stackoverflow) realized into the project that sanitizing user input before storing makes re-editing much more difficult. It's much easier to store the original and sanitize before writing it out to a medium where there could be security issues.

Comment: Sounds good, and just to make sure we're on the same page; the blobs are good for storing html and css elements such as '<div>' and 'background-color' etc.? I plan to develop my own serialization method to break down the templates and remove an actual '<div>' string of text in the database. Another site suggested the use of a hierarchy system or tree style system to store the html

Comment: @Tony what site? I'd be interested to know why they think that's an appropriate solution. A large blob field in any database can store the entire HTML document, complete with special symbols and whatever else you need in the template, as a nice plain string.

Comment: Someone on the mysql forum suggested the hierarchy style database. Would you recommend just storing the plain html or serializing it some way? I have read that actual html tags should not be included in a database (I am not sure the reasoning though). My apologies for all the questions, I just want to approach this the correct way, from the beginning

Comment: Think of this site as an extremely simplified browser based dreamweaver ha

Comment: @Tony the problem with making the DOM structure intrinsic to the database design, rather than simply storing the HTML itself, is that relational databases are optimized for *highly* structured, *highly* regular data. HTML is only somewhat structured and highly irregular.

Answer (score 0):

I want to first point out that, what you need is a parser not a serialising method. You can simply store the template, then when you read it out, parse each individual element and then build the editing form. Sort of like xtgem does. No need to serialise. Unless you already parsed the data in an array.

If each user has his own template, then the chances of multiple reads is very low. Almost nill. Flat files will do very well in this siiuation. No need to sanitise and better performance. Do not forget file locking though.

If you are returning data in text input or textarea elements, no problem with xss. You don't need to sanitise output either.

I agree with @Rex. When I was developing a forum, I found that storing the original was better. It allowed for easy editing.

It would be best to separate the files and parse them separately. Keep presentation separate from markup. 
Parsers have never been my forte however. So I can't help in that aspect. 
You can take a look at pcltemplate from http://phpconcept.net to see how the parser works. Maybe give you ideas.

Comment: Please excuse my misunderstanding, a parser is exactly what I am trying to develop. I would like to be able to include the css as well however...After looking at xtgem, it is similar to what I am trying to achieve